# plot 2 x variables R plotly barchart

Tags: r, plotly

[image]

I want to make the above graph in plotly where men and women variables are stacked together with the year as the x axis?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like below?

```
df = data.frame(
Year=rep(1999:2019,2),
Percent=rpois(42,4),
Sex=rep(c("Men","Women"),each=21))

library(plotly)
COLS = c("#ffd369","#015668")
df$Year = factor(df$Year)
```

side by side:

```
p = plot_ly(df,x=~Year,y=~Percent,name=~Sex,type='bar',colors=COLS,color=~Sex) %>%
layout(xaxis = list(title =NA),
legend = list(orientation = "h",xanchor = "center",x=0.5)
)
```

stacked:

```
p %>% layout(barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]